# Converting Table to associative array using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this HTML table

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Bore:</strong></td>
            <td>73</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Color:</strong></td>
            <td>Machine Black</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Diameter:</strong></td>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>PCD:</strong></td>
            <td>5x114.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Wheel Offset:</strong></td>
            <td>51</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Width:</strong></td>
            <td>9.5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

df = pd.read_html(response.request.url)
tb = df[0]
tb

             0                    1
0          Bore:                   73
1         Color:        Machine Black
2      Diameter:                   17
3           PCD:              5x114.3
4  Wheel Offset:                   51
5         Width:                  9.5
```

I want to:

1. convert column 0 as index/header and column 1 become its value.

   ```
   Bore    Color           Diameter   PCD       Wheel Offset   Width
   73      Machine Black   17         5x114.3   51             9.5
   ```
2. convert to associative array

I search high and low but couldn't find any answer.  Please help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index` and `transpose` functions to achieve this. Consider the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "pd.html"

df = pd.read_html(url)
tb = df[0]
tb = tb.set_index(0)
tb1 = tb.transpose()
print(tb1)
```

Results in output:

```
0 Bore:         Color: Diameter:     PCD: Wheel Offset: Width:
1    73  Machine Black        17  5x114.3            51    9.5
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am sure this will work.